# How do I create multiple configurations for the same class with Configuration Admin?

Tags: java, osgi

I'm working on an entity-component-system game engine that will utilize the OSGi framework.
I want users/developers to be able to create their own component types in a modular way, similar to the Bethesda Creation Kit.

[image: Creation Kit Object Window]

The way that I had thought about approaching this was to create a class that would represent a component type, then use the Configuration Admin to create configurations, but I'm not sure if my understanding is correct.

I have a class that I want to use as a Component type

```
@Component(
    configurationPid = "Species",
    configurationPolicy = ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE,
    service = Species.class
)
public final class Species {
    // ...
}
```

To test this, I created a command for Apache Gogo to create a `Species`. My thought was that I should be able to create multiple species with this command.

```
@Component(
    property = {
        CommandProcessor.COMMAND_SCOPE + "=species",
        CommandProcessor.COMMAND_FUNCTION + "=create"
    },
    service = CreateSpeciesCommand.class
)
public class CreateSpeciesCommand {

    /* L1 */

    @Reference(bind = "bindConfigurationAdmin")
    private ConfigurationAdmin configurationAdmin;

    @Descriptor("creates a species")
    public void create(@Descriptor("id of the species") final String speciesId) throws IOException, InvalidSyntaxException {
        final String filter = String.format("(%s=%s)", Constants.OBJECTCLASS, Species.class.getSimpleName());
        final Configuration[] existingConfigurations = configurationAdmin.listConfigurations(filter);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(existingConfigurations));

        final Configuration speciesConfiguration = configurationAdmin.getConfiguration(Species.class.getSimpleName(), "?");
        Dictionary<String, Object> configProperties = new Hashtable<>();
        configProperties.put(Constants.SERVICE_PID, "Species");

        speciesConfiguration.update(configProperties);
    }
}
```

But all that happens is that it modifies the configuration, instead of creating a new one.

What do I need to do to create multiple configurations for the same class with the Configuration Admin?

**2018-06-19 Edit:**

Making the changes specified by [Peter Kriens' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50906603/1066531):

- Add `@Designate` annotation to `Species` class
- Set `@Component#name` to something unique
- Set `@Component#configurationPolicy` to `ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE`
- Add `@ObjectClassDefinition` to `Species.Config` class
- Use `ConfigurationAdmin#getConfiguration` (`createConfiguration` does not exist, only this and `createFactoryConfiguration`) with the `@Component#name` as the pid

results in only one configuration being created, which gets updated with subsequent calls.

Comment: Please 1) fix your question title so that it is informative and summarizes your actual question/problem, and 2) try to hone your question to be more specific and thus a better fit for this site. If the latter is not possible, then the question might better be posted elsewhere on a non-stackexchange site.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OSGi Configuration Admin has 2 different types of configurations:

- Singleton – Has a PID
- Factory – Has a PID (for the instance of the factory) and a Factory PID for the 'group' of instances.

In OSGi >= 6, you can therefore do this:

```
 @Designate( ocd= Species.Config.class, factory=true )
 @Component( name = "species.pid", configurationPolicy=ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE )
 public class Species {
      @ObjectClassDefinition
      @interface Config {
          String id();
      }

      @Activate
      void activate( Config config) {
          System.out.println( config.id() );
      }
}
```

So now the command (extended with list+delete functions):

```
 @Component(
   property = {
     CommandProcessor.COMMAND_SCOPE + "=species",
     CommandProcessor.COMMAND_FUNCTION + "=create",
     CommandProcessor.COMMAND_FUNCTION + "=list",
     CommandProcessor.COMMAND_FUNCTION + "=delete"
   },
   service = CreateSpeciesCommand.class
 )
 public class CreateSpeciesCommand {
   @Reference
   ConfigurationAdmin configurationAdmin;

   public Configuration create(String speciesId) throws Exception {
     Configuration c = configurationAdmin.createFactoryConfiguration( "species.pid", "?");
     Hashtable<String,Object> d = new Hashtable();
     d.put("id", speciesId);
     c.update( d );
     return c;         
   }

   public Configuration[] list() throws Exception {
     return configurationAdmin.
        listConfigurations( "(service.factoryPid=species.pid)");
   }

   public boolean delete(String id) throws Exception {
     Configuration[] list = configurationAdmin.
        listConfigurations( "(&(service.factoryPid=species.pid)(id="+id+"))");
     if ( list == null) {
        return false;
     }
     for ( Configuration c : list ) {
        c.delete();
     }
     return true;
   }
}
```

Some notes:

- Written without compiling, so there might be some compile errors
- WebConsole is much nicer to create and delete Species
- Skipped the Gogo annotations for readability
- clearly no defense into 'filter' injection attacks

Comment: I tried implementing this, but it only ended up creating the one configuration, but kept updating after each call; I was looking for how to create a unique configuration per call. My answer has what worked for me.

Comment: I did make a mistake on the createConfiguration (should have been createFactoryConfiguration as you said.) However, after that change the code worked the first time.

Comment: I'll try again to see if perhaps I missed something, but when I tried it the first time, even after the `createFactoryConfiguration` change, it would only create on configuration.

Comment: It looks like your solution does work, I'm not sure what I did wrong the first couple times. One question I have is why does your solution cause new `Species` to be configured and activated immediately, whereas my answer only creates the configuration?

Comment: Not sure and I do not have the time to debug your code ... You should be able to figure this out now you have a working example.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a new configuration for each call, I needed to change the following things:

- Set the `@Component#factory` value for the `Species` class to something unique
- Use the `ConfigurationAdmin#createFactoryConfiguration` method instead of the `getConfiguration` method

I tried applying the changes specified by [Peter Kriens' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50906603/1066531):

- Add `@Designate` annotation to `Species` class
- Set `@Component#name` to something unique
- Set `@Component#configurationPolicy` to `ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE`
- Add `@ObjectClassDefinition` to `Species.Config` class
- Use `ConfigurationAdmin#getConfiguration` (`createConfiguration` does not exist, only this and `createFactoryConfiguration`) with the `@Component#name` as the pid; `createFactoryConfiguration` uses value from `@Component#factory`

which not only makes new configurations, but also activates the species component at the same time. Not sure why that is, but I'm looking into it.

## Updated Code

#### Species.java

```
package net.zephyrion.hummingbird.module.species;

import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Activate;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.ConfigurationPolicy;

import java.util.Objects;

@Component(
    factory = "Species",
    configurationPolicy = ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE,
    service = Species.class
)
public final class Species {

    @interface Config {
        String id() default "";
    }
    private Config config;

    @Activate
    public void configure(final Config config) {
        this.config = Objects.requireNonNull(config);
    }

    private String getId() {
        return config.id();
    }
}
```

#### CreateSpeciesCommand.java

```
package net.zephyrion.hummingbird.module.species;

import org.apache.felix.service.command.CommandProcessor;
import org.apache.felix.service.command.Descriptor;
import org.osgi.framework.InvalidSyntaxException;
import org.osgi.service.cm.Configuration;
import org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationAdmin;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Reference;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Dictionary;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.List;

@Component(
    property = {
        CommandProcessor.COMMAND_SCOPE + "=species",
        CommandProcessor.COMMAND_FUNCTION + "=create"
    },
    service = CreateSpeciesCommand.class
)
public class CreateSpeciesCommand {

    /* L1 */

    @Reference(bind = "bindConfigurationAdmin")
    private ConfigurationAdmin configurationAdmin;

    @Descriptor("creates a species")
    public void create(@Descriptor("id of the species") final String speciesId) throws IOException {
        try {
            final String factoryPid = Species.class.getSimpleName();
            final String filter = String.format("(&(id=%s)(service.factoryPid=%s))", speciesId, factoryPid);
            final boolean configurationExists = configurationAdmin.listConfigurations(filter) != null;
            if (!configurationExists) {
                final Configuration speciesConfiguration = configurationAdmin.createFactoryConfiguration(factoryPid, "?");
                Dictionary<String, Object> configProperties = new Hashtable<>();
                configProperties.put("id", speciesId);

                speciesConfiguration.update(configProperties);
            }
        }
        catch (InvalidSyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /* L2 */

    private void bindConfigurationAdmin(final ConfigurationAdmin configurationAdmin) {
        // TODO Obj.rnn
        this.configurationAdmin = configurationAdmin;
    }
}
```